# providing custom index.html file for electron-webpack

Tags: webpack, electron

How can I provide my custom index.html when using electron-webpack ?.

I am new to webpack, I managed to configure it with electron but I didn't have the webpack-dev-server watch my html file so I had to refresh every time I made a change, and this is why I tried electron-webpack.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?  I just came across the same problem and I don't know how to add my own index.html file into the electron-webpack project.

Answer (score 1):

First Welcome to Wonderfully Terrible World of Webpack! A powerful tool with a steep learning curve.

Basically any time you want to do anything non-standard (standard being simply bundling JS code together) you're going to need either a plugin or a loader.

For this problem you are trying to make a custom HTML file that webpack is aware of. html-webpack-plugin is going to be the plugin of choice. And adding it to your config file is really simple. If you provide your config I can help you with that or feel free to check out this great resource which will give you a run down of webpack, starting with easy material and getting more complicated as you go. The link below will take you to starting with html-webpack-config.

https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/getting-started/#setting-up-webpack-configuration

Comment: thank your for your quick response, and sorry for the delay, I have no `webpack.config.js`, I am using `electron-webpack` which is kind of module that take care of configuring webpack to make it suitable for developing electron app (provide hot reload and ... etc) I am using it with its default configuration (which is no configuration at all), in the default mode it take care of creating  an `index.html` for you using `html-webpack-plugin`, I want to provide my own `index.html` instead of the default one.

Comment: For future passer-bys: 1. Create a new `webpack.config.js` 2. Create a new `electron-webpack.json` 3. Add `webpack.config.js` to `electron-webpack.json`  [as mentioned here](https://webpack.electron.build/modifying-webpack-configurations#configure-electron-webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `src/index.ejs` file, it will be used to generate the index.html file.